# Multiindex to different columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, python-xarray

After I've read in a `netCDF` file via `xray`, I get a pandas `dataframe` with a `multiindex` like this:

```
                   temp
date       lat lon                            
2012-01-01 54  10  206
               11  207
           55  10  210
               11  214
2012-01-02 54  10  206
...                ...
```

Now I want to convert the `multiindex` into different columns to do statistical manipulations. I want to get a pd `dataframe` like this:

```
           temp_54_10 temp_54_11 temp_55_10 temp_55_11
date                                  
2012-01-01 206        207        210        214
2012-01-02 206        208        213        220
...                                         ...
```

It is possible to get a `dataframe` like this only with pandas or `xray` tools and if yes how can I do this?

Thanks in advance :)

p.s. I use `python 3.5.0`, `pandas 0.17.0` and `xray 0.6.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unstacking.  This assumes your dataframe is named `df`.

```
>>> df.unstack(['lat', 'lon'])
          temp               
lat         54        55     
lon         10   11   10   11
date                         
2012-1-1   206  207  210  214
2012-1-2   206  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If you wish to join the lat_lon values, you can do that as follows:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['lat_lon'] = ["{0}_{1}".format(lat, lon) for lat, lon in zip(df.lat, df.lon)]
>>> df.pivot(index='date', columns='lat_lon', values='temp')
lat_lon   54_10  54_11  55_10  55_11
date                                
2012-1-1    206    207    210    214
2012-1-2    206    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, with your comment I've solved the problem :)